# filling entry box from data gotten from code

Tags: python-3.x

I need an entry box that can be updated from inside code, such as

```
    ...
    title_text = tk.StringVar()
    e1 = tk.Entry(window, textvariable=title_text)
    #taking input from the user in the grid and storing it in a string variable
    e1.place(x=60, y=40)
    ...
```

I run code which gives me title_text information, how do i get python to update the Stringvar or whatever??

```
    ...
    def get_command(): #getting data from internet
        isbn_data = isbn_text.get()
        isbn_ret=(registry.bibformatters['labels'](meta(isbn_data)))
        isbn_ret1 = (isbn_ret.splitlines())
    ...
```

which returns
['Title:', 'Zinnia']
I can process this further with regex but can't get it to update the text entry box

Zinnia should be displayed in the title_text = tk.StringVar() box, notice I can get entry box data with .get option (isbn_text.get())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I figured out how to do this.
First, you need to use the textvariable name then use the set method and then put new_text into parenthesizes.

example  title_text.set(record[1]) "this uses the item 1 from record list"
or       title_text.set("Affair")  "this just puts 'Affair' in"